# Iframe URL that changes frequently

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I'd like to iframe an interactive map whose url changes very frequently. The url changes because it takes into account parameters for the map (like coordinates, activated layers, zoom level etc.). As soon as you navigate on the map, the url changes. I'd like to be able to share the parent page with the map in iframe, taking these url changes into account.

The url with his parameter values looks like this: `https://kartenn.region-bretagne.fr/kartoviz/?x=-179589&y=6124999&z=12.603072424400471&l=lycee&lb=osm1&config=demo/print.xml`

The parameter values in this url are: `x=-179589&y=6124999&z=12.603072424400471&l=lycee&lb=osm1`

Is it possible to pass these parameter values to the url of the parent page? Or is there another possibility?

Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to host the page every time the url changes.

Comment: That would only be possible, if the iframe and your main page shared the same origin - which I'm guessing is not the case here - or if the iframe'd service had a mechanism to explicitly communicate such information back to your page, using `postMessage` or something for cross-origin communication.

Comment: Indeed, the two pages don't have the same origin. How can I use ```postMessage``` here? And should I use it from the parent page or the iframe page? I have no experience with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Their is not a direct way to detect the URL changing in the iFrame, but if you add JS in the iframe you could do something like this.

```js
const observeUrlChange = () => {
  let oldHref = document.location.href
  const body = document.querySelector("body")
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    if (oldHref !== document.location.href) {
      oldHref = document.location.href
      top.postMessage(document.location.href, '*')
    }
  })
  observer.observe(body, { childList: true, subtree: true })
}

window.onload = observeUrlChange
```

Then in the parent page you can receive the message with:

```
let iframeUrl

window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  iframeUrl = event.data
}, false)
```